# $\langle\mathbb{R},d\rangle$ is not separable

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\langle\mathbb{R},d\rangle$ be a metric space,
where for all x,y in $\mathbb{R}$ $$ d(x,y)= \begin{cases}1 & x\neq y\\ 0\quad & x=y \end{cases}$$

**what i know about it**

- I know that any metric space $\mathbb{R}$ to be separable $\mathbb{R}$ needs to contain a dense countable subset .
- I also know that in case of discrete metric space of $\mathbb{R}$ , a singleton set is infact an open ball of radius 1.
- I also know $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable set and in  this case , $R$ have uncountable open balls.

> But how can i conclude by all this then $\mathbb{R}$ is not separable here or $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't contain any countable dense subset .

[ NOTE ] : while the linked question is same but asking area of that user is different . He was asking about why the singleton set is open or closed. And community give response according to it there  But  it's was understable to me but i want some beyond information's  which i already get. Thanks !!

Comment: The post [Prove that $\langle\mathbb{R}$, discrete metric$\rangle$ is not separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2474001/prove-that-langle-mathbbr-discrete-metric-rangle-is-not-separable) should answer your question. Please consider searching the site for a longer period, using an external engine such as Google if necessary : if you are an elementary beginner in topology, it is very likely that everything you need is already here in some form.

Comment: but in this , author ask different query and he got response according to it there.  I saw this one also before asking my question . But thanks , i will always do the same as per your instructions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this metric space every singleton set is open : $\{x\}=B(x,1)$. Hence, every subset is open which makes every subset is closed. So the closure of a countable set is itself and $\mathbb R $ is not countable.

Comment: Yeah , in this way it's become very easy , Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

If $D$ is dense in $(\Bbb R,d)$ it must intersect **every** open ball, i.e. every $\{x\}=B_d(x,1)$. What can you conclude about how many dense sets we have?

Comment: @AMITMITTAL All singletons are open balls here so open balls are not infinite.

Comment: $\{x\} \cap D \neq \emptyset \iff x \in D$.

Comment: Yeah it's cleared so $D$ which is any dense set must have uncountable no. Of elements. Thanks

Comment: @AMITMITTAL $D$ must be equal to $\Bbb R$, even.

Comment: Exactly , understood